# Hide and show using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, hide, show

I have many divs with ids in one class.How do I show one and hide the rest?
Here goes my HTML with 3 such divs

```
<div class="build">
   <div id="slide1">
      <!--slide1 elements -->
   </div>
   <div id="slide2">
      <!--slide2 elements-->
   </div>
   <div id="slide3">
      <!--slide2 elements-->
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what ive tried with JS:

```
if (exp_id == "a_exp1") {
    new_exp_id = exp_id;

    $("#right").html("<div><img id='myimage1' onclick='changeimage1()' src='images/build_i.png'/>")
}

function changeimage1() {
    for (var n = 1; n <= 3; n++) {
        if (new_exp_id == "a_exp" + n) {


            $('.build').hide();
            $('.build').find('#slide' + n).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So, if its `a_exp1`, it should correspond to slide1, if its `a_exp2`, it should correspond to slide2 and so on.

I need to show one div and hide the rest. How do i do this? I have hidden the entire class in the beginning of my HTML.

Comment: once you hide parent you can not see its child not even if you set `display:block !important`

Comment: use jquery widget? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Have you tried: `$('.build').children('div').click(function() { $(this).show().siblings.hide(); });`?

Comment: @Ronak That's a nice snippet, perhaps make it an answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.build').children('div').click(function()
{
    $(this).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Im not sure what this click function here does?

Comment: Thanks anyway!, ill try and use this!

Answer (score 2):

provide all the div's the same class let say '.chat' and then hide all the div's with class '.chat' and show the one you want to show for ex

```
<div id="slide1" class="chat">
<div id="slide2" class="chat">
<div id="slide3" class="chat">
```

and now if you want to show the div with id `slide3` you can do something like this

```
$('.chat').hide();
 $('#slide3').show();
```

and if you are using any click event to show and hide stuff then work with live click instead of just click

```
$('#somebutton').live("click",function(){
     $('.chat').hide();
 $('#slide3').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it with a "hide all, show one" method which allows you to not care which one was previously shown, just the one you want to show:

```
function showSlide(currentSlide) {
    $(".build").children().hide(); 
    $("#slide" + currentSlide).show();
}
```

Then you can just `showSlide(1)` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $(".build div").click(function () {
       $(this).siblings().hide().end().show(); 
    });
});
```